# The webserver bundled with Corda throws a PermissionException during startup

Tags: corda

The webserver bundled with Corda throws a net.corda.client.rpc.PermissionException during startup.

The exception message is: "User not authorized to perform RPC call nodeInfo with target []"

I'm building the nodes using gradle and then launching the nodes using runnodes.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your build.gradle, under the deployNodes task, you need to ensure that the rpcUsers parameter provides the required permissions.

For example, when running in a test environment, you could pass in "ALL". Your rpcUsers parameter would look like:

```
rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
```